# Vector dot product of corresponding rows using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to compute the vector dot product of the corresponding rows of two 2 dimensional arrays `u` and `v` in numpy. The rows of `u` are unit vectors. Here is some sample code that illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
import numpy as np

u = np.array([[1, 0], [.6, .8], [0, 1]])
v = np.array([[1, 2], [3 ,  4], [5, 6]])
```

I naively tried to use numpy's `dot` method, which returns an error as follows:

```
np.dot(u, v)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-146fe9079c1e> in <module>
----> 1 np.dot(u,v)

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (3,2) and (3,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

It's straightforward to define a function that produces the desired behavior:

```
def mydot(a, b):
    return np.sum(a*b,axis=1,keepdims=True)
mydot(u,v)
```

```
array([[1.],
[5.],
[6.]])
```

However, this seems a bit clunky and leaves me with the suspicion that I'm missing something. Is there a more straightforward numpy way to do this?

Comment: "column vector of unit vectors" is a bit misleading here

Comment: The issue here is that `u` and `v` are **not** 1-dimensional vectors.  They are interpreted as shape of (3, 2) so dot product is undefined for that.

Comment: `dot` with 2d arrays is matrix-multiplication, with the usual `columns with rows` rule.  This behavior should be described well enough in the docs!

Answer (score 2):

Your way works fine. At the same time, you can use `matmul` with an extra dimension to multiply stacks of 1x2 by 2x1 matrices:

```
u[..., None] @ v[:, None, :]
```

The biggest difference between `matmul` and `dot` is that `matmul` broadcasts the initial dimensions while `dot` combines them.

But the fastest way is probably `einsum`:

```
np.einsum('ij,ij->i', u, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.dot` acts as a matrix multiplication when used for 2D arrays so `np.dot(v,u.T)` this will not give you an error. But for dot product you can use this:

```
np.sum(v*u,axis=1)
```

`v*u` simply broadcast the 2D array and axis in `np.sum()` allows you to select the dimension in which you want to calculate the dot product. I hope you got it.